# Alternate to the 'use' keyword in Codeigniter

Tags: php, graphql, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter for a project and I want to incorporate a library into the project, but it is setup with various files using namespaces and the `'use'` keyword to include the required files. How do I convert this to work with Codeigniter? Do I just replace every `use LibName\Something\Something` with a `require()` statement, or do I do something different?

I'd like top use this library in CI3 unless there's a better way:

https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `use` statement in order to use the library. So, don't go hacking graphql-php.

Since the library uses Composer it's very easy to put that autoloader to work with CodeIgniter. In /application/config/config.php set the following "Composer auto-loading" section

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

Read the comments in config.php if you have changed the location of the "vendor" folder from the usual spot.

After that, you use the standard PHP syntax to use and instantiate classes in the library.

You should probably avoid namespacing your application, meaning anything using CodeIgniter's core classes. That approach has worked for me when combining libraries like `graphql-php` (e.g. `PhpSpreadSheet`) and CodeIgniter.